# Anyway to change the sheet order?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there anyway to change to order of specified sheet which already existed?
I see there's API called `sheet.getIndex()`, but there's no set's.
The only way now seems call `insertSheet()`.

```
insertSheet(optName, optSheetIndex, optAdvancedArgs)
```

You can specify the index with `optSheetIndex`. Any idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can achieve this with [setActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#setActiveSheet) and [moveActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#moveActiveSheet).