# Recalculating formulas in a copy of a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet that I use for attendance that is linked to a Google form that students use to sign in. I'm using a script to copy the spreadsheet to a new file but not the form that is linked to it. Everything seems to be working, except some of my tabs show #REF! and I have to go into each cell and manually refresh for everything to appear properly. It seems that the error is due to the order that the sheets are copied, whereby if a formula is looking for a sheet that is yet to be copied, it returns an error!? One workaround I discovered is to rearrange the tabs in the sheet so that the ones with my raw data from forms get copied first, although, I'd prefer if I could have those cells recalculate and have my raw data tabs at the end. Here is the script I'm using:

```
function backUp() 
{
  //Open old spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Prepare new name
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MMMM dd, yyyy' 'h:mm a");
  var name = spreadsheet.getName() + " Copy " + formattedDate;
  //Prepare file system objects
  var oldfile = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId());
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1MFp9_z1hs4e-tpa2m_5SUKorkCbqLruZ");
  //create new spreadsheet
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
  //move to destination folder
    var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId());
    var parents = newFile.getParents();
    destination.addFile(newFile);
  //copy all sheets to new spreadsheet
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName(sheet.getName());
  });
  //remove empty sheet (created with new spreadsheet)
  newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
}
```

Comment: Instead of this: `sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName(sheet.getName());
  });` try this `newSpreadsheet=spreadsheet.copy(name);`

Comment: I tried it, but it just created a new blank spreadsheet with the linked form.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, if the copied sheet has formulas that including references to sheets that don't exist yet on the target spreadsheet they will return an error.

You could copy the sheets following the data flow (from raw data to final formulas) and once all the sheets are on the destination spreadsheet reorder them by using `moveActiveSheet(position)`

Related

- [How to move sheet within Google Spreadsheeet using apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16401749/1595451)
- [Anyway to change the sheet order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14533869/1595451)

Comment: Thanks, I got it figured out.